# I can add data in the console, but there is an error in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, arguments

Bir veritabanım var. Şu şekilde oluşturdum:

```
rails generate model Lottery ref_no:string:index user_id:integer send:boolean
```

Then I make the "send" field "default: false".

```
rails db:migrate
```

Now when I connect to the rails console and run this code, everything is fine:

```
Lottery.create!(ref_no: 'test', user_id: 1)
```

**Output:**

```
#<Lottery id: 1, ref_no: "test", user_id: 1, send: false, created_at: ..., updated_at: ...>
```

The above command writes the data to the database and automatically sets the send field to false.
**When I use the same command inside a controller it gives the following error:**

```
> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Then there was an interesting situation. If I delete the "send" field from the "Lottery" table, the code worked without error in the controller.

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Don't name your column `send`, it overwrites Ruby built-in `Object#send` method and that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: Thank you Marek Lipka. It worked without errors when I changed the name of the field to "sent_status".

Comment: Please take the time and translate your complete post, there is a myriad of webpages to help you doing so. It might otherwise be understood as not really nice or of a low-effort question.

Comment: @ozbilgic Do you mind writing up a proper answer, that can be accepted so that this question is marked "close"? Otherwise we will loose peoples attention on this (already solved) question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@marek-lipka's answer.
**Since Ruby is the built-in Object#send method, we cannot use "send" in column naming.**